# rbenv ruby install fail ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rbenv

Here is the error log

```
Downloading ruby-2.2.0.tar.gz... -> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/7671e394abfb5d262fbcd3b27a71bf78737c7e9347fa21c39e58b0bb9c4840fc
Installing ruby-2.2.0...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20141225-7-g4aeeac2)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20150106233051.25615 Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20150106233051.25615.log

Last 10 log lines:

compiling ossl_x509store.c
compiling ossl_engine.c
compiling ossl_ocsp.c
compiling ossl_config.c
compiling ossl_digest.c
installing default openssl libraries
linking shared-object openssl.so
make[2]: Leaving directory /tmp/ruby-build.20150106233051.25615/ruby-2.2.0/ext/openssl'
make[1]: Leaving directory/tmp/ruby-build.20150106233051.25615/ruby-2.2.0'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

I'm not sure what to do here. I tried this but when I type `ruby -v` it still tells me I have the old version.

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf bison libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm3 libgdbm-dev
```

Thanks for any comments given, much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this might help you? https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/526

Answer (score 8, accepted):

install these dependencies first and then retry worked for me on 14.04 for ruby 2.2.0 with rbenv

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm3 libgdbm-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

All of other anwsers failed for me...

and after lot of failed attempts and research I found out those workarounds for many versions:

**2.1.1**

```
curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/mislav/a18b9d7f0dc5b9efc162.txt | rbenv install --patch 2.1.1
```

**2.0.0-p451**

```
curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/LeonB/10503374/raw | rbenv install --patch 2.0.0-p451
```

**2.0.0-p247**

```
cat <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/patches/ruby/changeset_r45225.diff) <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/patches/ruby/changeset_r45240.diff) | sed -E 's/^((---|\+\+\+) )(a|b)\/([^ ]+\s+\(revision [0-9]+\))$/\1\4/' | sed '/rl_delete_text/d' | rbenv install -p 2.0.0-p247
```

Source: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/526

Hope i could help anyone.

Comment: You save my life. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu and or Debian than you can try to install libffi-dev via apt-get.

```
$ apt-get install libffi-dev
```

I did a little research around the forums and I found this on the official rbenv Question and Answer section.

https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/wiki#build-failure-of-fiddle-with-ruby-220